# How to hook up Korg EX-8000 to a computer w/o a keyboard?

Tags: midi, computer, korg

I have a Korg EX-8000 synth I bought at a thrift store, but no midi keyboard and would like to know how to hook up to my computer so I can test to see if it works.  I just ordered a MIDI to USB cable.  What else am I going to need so I can test the unit on my computer?  Or can it even be done with the Korg EX-8000 w/o keyboard on a computer?

Thanks to the board so much for any help/advice.

Comment: There are free editor programs for the EX-8000, e.g. this one: http://ctrlr.org/korg-dw-8000/ (you need to download the ctrlr programme itself and the "panel" for the DW-8000, which is the keyboard version of the EX-8000; see the documentation).

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to just check that it works and you are happy using something simpler than a sequencer, you could use a virtual MIDI keyboard - that runs on your computer and will allow you to play notes out of your MIDI interface using your computer. An example is http://vmpk.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: Yes, for just seeing if it works, that seems an excellent choice.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  To hook up unit to computer via midi-usb cord and to see if, once connected, I can play sounds from the Korg on the computer and test all different sounds that unit produces using a 'virtual MIDI keyboard.'  That's assuming the unit actually puts out midi signal for program to detect.  Thanks to all for reply.  Have to wait for midi-usb cable to arrive in a few days to attempt.

Comment: @Rafael Your Uncle Bob's suggestion of using an editor is also good, as is Laurence Payne's plan of using a sequencer; it's good to have a plan B in case it's the software, rather than hardware, that's the problem. Interesting purchase - hope it works!

Answer (score 3):

You need a program on your computer that outputs MIDI data (in much the same way as a keyboard would).   These programs are commonly called 'sequencers'.   [Here's a free one](https://www.audacityteam.org/download/)

Whoops!  That's an audio-only program.   Try [this](https://www.tracktion.com/products/t7-daw) for MIDI.

Or if you're happy working with notation try [this](https://musescore.org/en)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Wouldn't I need a program with a keyboard so I can test the outputs of the Korg by playing the keyboard on the computer and changing settings on Korg for different sounds?  I downloaded the Audacity program per your recommendation.  Just have to figure out how to use, as I am quite ignorant when it comes to this sort of thing.  Thank you very much for the reply and your time and any additional help/suggestion greatly appreciated,

Comment: I don’t think musescore will send MIDI data out to an external sound module, it only takes it in from a keyboard. Finale and Sibelius will do it, though.

Comment: Also audacity doesn’t do MIDI at all, only audio. So while the answer is good, the specific recommended software won’t help.

Comment: Sorry, I gave you a bum steer with Audacity - thats just for audio,   See amended reply - older versions of Tracktion have gone free.   @Todd Wilcox, MuseScore definitely will use any available MIDI output.   I've just tried and successfully routed it to both a Kurzweil PC3 keyboard and a Korg X5DR module